# intellij IDEA import settings

Tags: intellij-idea, import

I am trying to import settings from another person's IntelliJ IDEA installation. I followed the instructions that JetBrains provide [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) and I was presented with the messages that suggest that it has worked. But on restarting my IDE I find that the settings have not been imported but the settings are exactly as they were before I tried to import the other settings.

If it helps I use IntelliJ 12.1.7

EDIT: I just tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051991/importing-jar-file-into-intellij-idea) but I had no success.

Answer (score 5):

If cloud IDE settings syncing is turned on, you can't import new settings, and needs to be disabled first. Please, see the screenshots below for how to do it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works. This should be marked as the answer. Thank you! It's a shame I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: @RémyMachado Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

After importing, you have to explicitly pick up those settings. I.e. if you imported *code style* settings you have to go to Idea settings and explicitly pick this imported code style from drop down list.

Comment: I'm not seeing the new imported settings in the "Settings" area of IDEA.

Comment: Which settings exactly do you import? Code style?

Comment: To avoid having anything missing I'm trying to import all the settings from the other user.

Comment: So, find IDEA's log file: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108 . Then try to import settings, do you see anything wrong? If not everything shall be ok. If the settings you import are all defaults, they will be probably overwritten. That's all. If in settings you import there is some custom definition like custom code style profile, you have to pick it up in dialog Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Scheme dropdown list.